# JSTL number handling

Tags: java, jstl, el

I set the session variable like below

```
getSession(true).setAttribute("entriesCount", "10");
```

then the call below returning nothing in jstl.

```
<c:out value="${#session.entriesCount}"/>
```

Comment: EL tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17477_01/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<c:out value="${entriesCount}"/>
```

or

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.entriesCount}"/>
```

[This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7) seems useful:

> the expression ${name} refers to a scoped variable named name. That scoped variable can reside in page, request, session, or application scope. The expression language searches those scopes, in that order, for scoped variables.

and

> The implicit objects listed above let you explicitly access variables stored in a specific scope; for example, if you know that the name scoped variable resides in session scope, the expression ${sessionScope.name} is equivalent to ${name}, but the latter unnecessarily searches the page and request scopes before finding the name scoped variable in session scope

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read about `#session` and what's it? You should be fine just with `<c:out value="${entriesCount}"/>`.